# Symfony 2.1 - Session Events (Garbage Collector)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

In my application i am storing some session associated data - let's call it a cart mechanism.

Cart have associated session id and products are related to certain carts. Pretty basic.

I'd like to listen to Symfony's session destroy event, so I can delete unused products from the databse. Any ideas how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to generate event like this. 
You can update last session usage in db (in kernel.request event listener) and simply delete it in cron task after **session.storage.options.lifetime** seconds are passed.